# Rails Relationship (has_many/belongs_to) Completed

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So it's been quite a bit of time since I played with relationships and I want to make sure I've done it right.

In my model for Client I have:

```
class Client < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :projects, dependent: :destroy
end
```

In my model for Projects I have:

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :client
end
```

So I know that's set. Then to grab projects I put in my projects controller:

```
def create
 @client = Client.find(params[:client_id])
 @project = @client.project.new(project_params)
 flash[:notice] = "Project created successfully" if @client.project << @project
 respond with @project, location: admin_project_path
end
```

Would I need to put something in my show that does the same?

Anything else I'm missing for relationships?

Comment: Just checking, but in the models it is actually `belongs_to :client` and `has_many :projects` with the colon correct?  In your view there are a few ways to do it, but `@client.projects` would contain the client's projects so to loop `@client.projects.each do | proj |` etc would loop through that clients projects.  Is that what you are asking about?

Comment: Fixed the missing colons. Yeah I'm just wanting to make sure I make it easy to access the client's projects.

Comment: Did the below work for you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would think this:

```
def create
  @client = Client.find(params[:client_id])
  @project = @client.project.new(project_params)
  flash[:notice] = "Project created successfully" if @client.project << @project
  respond with @project, location: admin_project_path
end
```

Would look more like:

```
def create
  @client = Client.find(params[:client_id])
  @project = @client.projects.new(project_params)
  if @project.save
    # do success stuff 
  else
    # do failure stuff
  end
end
```

Note that

```
@project = @client.project.new(project_params)
```

should be:

```
@project = @client.projects.new(project_params)
```

As Yechiel K says, no need to do:

```
@client.project << @project
```

Since:

```
@project = @client.projects.new(project_params)
```

will automatically set `client_id` on the new `@project`. BTW, if you want to add a `project` to the `client` manually, then it's:

```
@client.projects << @project
```

(Note `projects` vs. `project`.)

In the off chance that there is not a `client` with `params[:client_id]`, then `@client = Client.find(params[:client_id])` will throw an error. You should probably include a rescue block. Alternatively, I prefer:

```
def create
  if @client = Client.find_by(id: params[:client_id])
    @project = @client.projects.new(project_params)
    if @project.save
      # do success stuff 
    else
      # do failure stuff
    end
  else
    # do something when client not found
  end
end
```

Also, `respond with` isn't a thing. `respond_with` is a thing. (I believe it's been moved to a separate gem, `responders`.) It's unclear from your code if you're needing different responses, say, for `html` and `js`. If not, then I think it would be more like:

```
def create
  if @client = Client.find_by(id: params[:client_id])
    @project = @client.projects.new(project_params)
    if @project.save
      flash[:notice] = "Project created successfully"
      redirect_to [@client, @project]
    else
      # do failure stuff
    end
  else
    # do something when client not found
  end
end
```

This assumes that your routes look something like:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :clients do 
    resources :projects
  end

end
```

In which case rails will resolve `[@client, @project]` to the correct route/path.

As DaveMongoose mentions, you *could* move `@client = Client.find_by(id: params[:client_id])` into a `before_action`. This is quite common. [Here's](http://craftingruby.com/posts/2015/05/31/dont-use-before-action-to-load-data.html) one discussion of why not to do that. Personally, I used to use `before_action` like this, but don't any more. As an alternative, you could do:

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController 

  ...

  def create 
    if client 
      @project = client.projects.new(project_params)
      if @project.save
        flash[:notice] = "Project created successfully"
        redirect_to [client, @project]
      else
        # do failure stuff
      end
    else
      # do something when client not found
    end
  end

private

  def client 
    @client ||= Client.find_by(id: params[:client_id])
  end

end
```

Taking this a bit further, you could do:

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController 

  ...

  def create 
    if client 
      if new_project.save
        flash[:notice] = "Project created successfully"
        redirect_to [client, new_project]
      else
        # do failure stuff
      end
    else
      # do something when client not found
    end
  end

private

  def client 
    @client ||= Client.find_by(id: params[:client_id])
  end

  def new_project 
    @new_project ||= client.projects.new(project_params)
  end

end
```

Comment: Very comprehensive answer! One other thing that might be worth mentioning would be moving the `@client = ...` line into a `before_action` if other actions (such as show) are also client-specific

Answer (score 2):

I would replace this line:

```
flash[:notice] = "Project created successfully" if @client.project << @project
```

with:

```
flash[:notice] = "Project created successfully" if @project.save
```

No need to manually add `@project` to `@client.projects`, it gets added automatically when you create it using `@client.projects.new`, the only thing you missed was that creating something using `.new` doesn't persist it in the DB, that gets accomplished by calling `@project.save`.

For your show action, I'm not sure if you mean the client's show page or the project's, but in either case, you would retrieve it using `params[:id]` (unless you were using some nested routing).

Comment: I actually had @project.save at one point. I'll probably use friendly id at some point for passing params.